# Can't find div for styling (tranform zoom) in javascript script tag in shadow dom of polymer 2.0 element

Tags: css, polymer-2.0

I am creating a polymer 2.0 PWA / Website. I have a problem with accessing a div container (I wish to zoom in and zoom out the div based on a user input).

In shadow dom with template dom if I am not able to get the element in Javascript so that on user action (like button click or slider) movement I can zoom the div.

I tried document getElementsByClassName, shadowroot search. I can see in shadow dom that this div is present. just not able to access it in javascript function in Polymer.

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('containerMap')[0]; // 
returns null in console can't find the element in shadow Dom
      var el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('someid'); // returns 
            null in console also tried '#someid' still null
    console.log('shadowRoot el = '+JSON.stringify(el));
    var elx = document.getElementById('someid'); // returns null in 
                                                   console
    console.log('shadowRoot el = '+JSON.stringify(elx));
      //var el = this.$.someid; // does not find the element
      // tried this.$['#someid'] this.$$('#someid') // does not work
    console.log(el);
```

Here's the full code (removed few unwanted code elements so that focus is on the problem in hand)

MyApp.html

```
 <link rel="lazy-import" href="epicsprint-page.html">

 <dom-module id="my-app">
   <template is="dom-bind">
     <style>
       ....
     </style>
     ....

<app-header-layout >

    <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
         <div style="float:left; width:10%;">
           <paper-icon-button id="menuElement" icon="icons:menu" drawer-toggle halign="left"></paper-icon-button>
         </div>
    </div>

  <div fit class="content">
        <!-- IRON PAGES MAIN CONTENT -->
        <iron-pages
            selected="[[page]]"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="not-found-404"
            role="main">
          <epicsprint-page name="epicsprint-page" user="{{user}}" 
             signedin="{{signedIn}}" statusknown="{{statusKnown}}" > 
          </epicsprint-page>
                  .....

      </div>
      </app-header-layout>
   </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>
</template>
 <script>

</script>
    ...

    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
  </script>
 </dom-module>
```

Element: epicspring-page.html

```
<dom-module id="epicsprint-page">
 <template is="dom-bind">
   <style include="shared-styles">

  :host {
    padding: 10px;
     font-family:'Fira Sans', sans-serif;

  }

a paper-button,
a:hover paper-button,
a:link paper-button,
a:active paper-button,
a:visited paper-button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 35px;
}


.page { overflow:auto; width: 90%; height: 100%; }
.containerMap { width:100%;  background: grey; }


.error-content{
  width: 80wh;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

/*************/
.board­__sprint {
  /*background: #5ba4cf;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  padding: 20px;
     overflow-x: auto;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }

  .list {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     /*background: #d2d7e5;*/
      width: 300px;
    padding: 1px;

    }

    .list-content {
      max-height: 80%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding-right: 5px;
      /*margin-right: -5px;*/
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .list-name {
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
    }

   .add-ticket {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #61bd4f 0, #5aac44 
         100%);
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
    }

   .ticket {
      /*background: white;*/
      flex: 0 0 auto;
       margin: 5px;
       width: 200px;
      height: 70px;
      align-items: center;
      white-space: normal;
   }

    .ticket-title {
      width: 100%;
     padding: 20px;
   }
   /*********/

  </style>

  <iron-ajax
      id="getEpicSprintMap"
      method="GET"
      url="{{url}}"
      handle-as="json"
      content-type="application/json"
      on-response="handleResponseGetEpicSprintMap"
      on-error="handleErrorGetEpicSprintMap"
      last-response="{{mapsData}}"
      last-error="{{lastError}}">
  </iron-ajax>

  <div style="width: 100%">
     <div style="float:left;">
        <div><h5></h5></div>
         <paper-icon-button src="../images/icons/help-icon-png.png" 
      on-tap="showHelpDialog"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
  <div style="float:right;">
    <div><h5></h5></div>
    <paper-icon-button src="../images/icons/support-icon-png.png" 
      on-tap="showHelpDialog"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
</div>

 <template is="dom-if" if="[[signedin]]">
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[mapsData.successFlag]]">

    <div style="float: center;">
          <h5 style="color: white; font-size: 12px; text- 
   align:left;">&nbsp;</h5>
    </div>
    <div style="float: center; display: flex">
        <iron-image src="../images/logo.png" preload 
    sizing="contain"
          on-tap="reloadEpics" style="width:200px; height:200px; 
    margin:auto;" ></iron-image>
    </div>
    <div style="float: center;">
        <h1 style="color: white" class="launchAmount">Epics & 
    Sprints</h1>
        <h2 style="color: white" class="launchAmount">Number of 
   sprints that an Epic spans</h2>
    </div>

 <input id="test" min="1" max="1000" value='1000' step="1" 
     onchange="showVal(this.value)" type="range"/>
 <div class="containerMap" id="someid">
   <div class="page">
      <div class="content">
      <div class="board­__sprint">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{mapsData.data}}" 
        as="row">
        <div class="list">
          <div class="list­-content">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <iron-image class=""
                           src="../images/icons/epic-icon-png.png"
                           preload
                           sizing="contain"
                           style="width:50px; height:50px; margin- 
         left: 50px;" ></iron-image>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
              <h3 class="sprintTitle" style="color: white; font- 
    size: 15px;background: black; padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
                <b>Epic:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>[[row.key]]
              </h3>
              <h3 class="sprintTitle" style="color: white; font- 
   size: 15px;background: black; padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
                [[row.title]]
              </h3>
            </div>
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row.sprint}}" 
    as="sprint">
                  <div class="ticket">
                      <paper-card style="float:center; width: 95%" 
    class$="{{_computedCardColorStories()}}">
                        <div style="width: 100%;">
                          <div style="float:left; width: 10%" 
   style$="{{getRandomInt(0, 20)}}">
                            <h7>&nbsp;</h7>
                          </div>
                          <div style="float:left; width: 90%; text- 
    align: center; padding: 10px;">
                              <h7 style="color: black; font-size: 
      18px; text-align:center;">[[sprint]]</h7>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                      </paper-card>
                  </div>
              </template>
            </div>
        </div>
  </template>
</div>

  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</template>
</template>

</template>

  </template>

<script>

/**
* @polymer
* @extends HTMLElement
*/
class EpicSprintMapPage extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'epicsprint-page'; }

  constructor() {
      super();
    }

  ready() {
    super.ready();
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      user: { type: Object, notify: true, readOnly: false, observer: '_userChanged' },
      signedin: { type: Boolean, notify: true, readOnly: false, observer: '_signedinChanged' },
      statusKnown: { type: Boolean, notify: true, readOnly: false, observer: '_statusChanged' },
      localSettings : { type: Object, notify: true, readOnly: false },
      mapsData: { type: Object, notify: true },
      filterFromDate : { type: String, notify: true },
      filterToDate: { type: String, notify: true },
      defaultSprintVelocity: { type: Number, value: 0, notify: true },
      zoomVal: { type: Number, value: 100, notify: true },
      }
    };

  _userChanged(user){
    this.user = user;
  }

  _signedinChanged(signedin){
    this.signedin = signedin;
  }

  _statusChanged(statusKnown){
    this.statusKnown = statusKnown;
  }

  showVal()
  {
    var zoomScale = Number(this.zoomVal)/100;
    console.log('zoomScale = '+zoomScale);
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('containerMap')[0]; // returns null in console can't find the element in shadow Dom
    var el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('someid'); // returns null in console also tried '#someid' still null
    console.log('shadowRoot el = '+JSON.stringify(el));
    var elx = document.getElementById('someid'); // returns null in console
    console.log('shadowRoot el = '+JSON.stringify(elx));
    //var el = this.$.someid; // doesn't find the element
// tried this.$['#someid'] this.$$('#someid')
    console.log(el);

    transformOrigin = [0,0];
    el = el || instance.getContainer();
    var p = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o"],
    s = "scale(" + zoomScale + ")",
    oString = (transformOrigin[0] * 100) + "% " + (transformOrigin[1] * 100) + "%";
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        el.style[p[i] + "Transform"] = s;
        el.style[p[i] + "TransformOrigin"] = oString;
    }
    el.style["transform"] = s;
    el.style["transformOrigin"] = oString;
  }



}//end Polymer

   window.customElements.define(EpicSprintMapPage.is, EpicSprintMapPage);
  </script>

 </dom-module>
```

I am expecting I can find the element in shadow dom and be able to style the element and mimick zoom in out functionality by transforming the div.

I am not sure how to get the element and what syntax it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove :

```
<template is="dom-bind">
...
</template>
```

You can use `dom-bind` template in index.html in  order to binding without to defining new custome element.  Then you can select your div element with `this.shadowRoot...`
For more information about [dom-bind](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates)

**EDİT**

As there is some variable which I don't know the values, But keep in your mind that if `dom-if` statement is false then its content does not render. So, you can not access any element inside.

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. Thanks a ton. Just for newbies ... would you be able to explain in simple words how "dom-bind" affects. What I understand is if the element needs to be attached to root directly without Polymer binding then you remove template is "dom-bind". That way all the elements in the template can be directly visible in shadowRoot for access. BUT ... they will not be updated dynamically by Polymer as binding is not enabled. is that correct? Thanks a ton for your quick reply and resolution.